# _OBJC_CLASS_$_GMDCircleLoader", referenced from: error

Tags: objective-c, xcode, linker-errors

I am using [GMDCircleLoader](https://github.com/gabemdev/GMDCircleLoader) in my project. I imported(Dragged GMDCircleLoader folder AND clicked on copy and also checked targets) the required folder to my project. I can import the header file and coded what was required.
But when I try to compile, I get the following error in Xcode 7.2 attached as
[image] above. The DashboardViewController.m file is already added in the Build Phases/Compile Sources so .m file not compiling is not an issue.
I looked on the net and also learned that this error comes when the related framework is not imported. I have imported frameworks such as QuartzCore, CoreGraphics. 
Tried looking for all possible solutions but no luck yet.
Can anyone please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you look in the build log, in the steps before it gets to the error you posted, do you see a compile step for `GMDCircleLoader.m`?  If "no", that's your problem.  If "yes", what does it say?

Comment: Hey @PhillipMills, No, I cannot see the compile step of GMDCircleLoader.m. What can I do to make it work?

Comment: Select that file in the project navigator and use the file inspector to add it to your target.

Comment: When I select that file, Target Membership is not visible in the file inspector.

Comment: Odd.  Try removing it from your project and then using File->Add Files To...  menu option to add it back in.

Comment: Target Membership option comes when the folder containing .h and .m file is selected and it is checked, but when i click on .m alone, it is not showing up. Is that okay?